# call multiple figures in a single reference

Tags: floats, cref

I have a sentence in my thesis that needs to call to five individual figures (Fig.s 2-6), but I cannot seem to get that to work. I have tried various options:

```
(Fig.s \ref{A},\ref{B},\ref{C},\ref{D},\ref{E},\ref{F}).
(Fig.s \crefrange{A,B,C,D,E,F}).
(Fig.s \cref{A},\cref{B},\cref{C},\cref{D},\cref{E},\cref{F}).
(Fig.s \cref{A, B, C, D, E, F}).
```

However none of them yield the desired result. My current best result is (Fig.s 2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: I‘m afraid you need to provide code, we can copy and compile. Because when we can do it, it means, you supplied all necessary info, e.g. about your preamble.

Comment: Running `\crefrange{A,B,C,D,E,F}` should be giving you an invalid-syntax error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that the output of both `(\Crefrange{A}{E})` and `(\Cref{A,B,C,D,E})` is `(Fig.s 2-6)`, I suggest you insert the following instructions in the preamble -- after loading the `cleveref` package, naturally:

```
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Fig.s}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{cleveref}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Fig.s}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{figure}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{A}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{B}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{C}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{D}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{E}

(\Crefrange{A}{E}) % or, if you prefer, '(\Cref{A,B,C,D,E})'
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to simplify the example, but appear to have made it more complicated instead. What I actually want is (Fig.s 25-30). Your answer gets me (Fig.s 31-36), and what is supposed to be (Fig. 1) is now (Fig. 7), as the numbering of figures has changed.

Comment: Are you including the instructions `\stepcounter{figure} \refstepcounter{figure}\label{A} \refstepcounter{figure}\label{B} \refstepcounter{figure}\label{C} \refstepcounter{figure}\label{D} \refstepcounter{figure}\label{E}` in your document? If you do, do please remove these instructions. Of course, do keep `\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Fig.s} \newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}` in the preamble.

Comment: Removing those yields: lorem ipsum (?? - ??.

Comment: @MacMcMahan - Did you change the two arguments of `\Crefrange{A}{E}` as needed for your document?

Comment: `\Crefrange{A,B,C,D,E}` did not work, but `\Crefrange{A}{E}` worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @MacMcMahan - There's a huge difference between `\Crefrange{A}{E}` and `\Crefrange{A,B,C,D,E}` -- the former can be compiled, the latter should be causing a serious error... `\Crefrange` expects two arguments, not a single argument consisting of a list of items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cleveref` to achieve what You want

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}

\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{example figure}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{example figure}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{example figure}
\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
 

The single figure ref \cref{fig1}.
Two figures ref \cref{fig1,fig2}
And more refs at once \crefrange{fig1}{fig3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP needs "Fig.s", not "Figs.", as the plural form of the label.

Comment: Maybe, but the main idea is the same)

Comment: Let's see if the OP weighs in on this topic. I got the impression, quite possibly incorrectly, that the OP really needs "Fig.s", not "Figs."...

Comment: OP here: I have not settled on a formatting style for the plural of Fig. yet, that was simply what I am using currently. I can change it easily enough when I do decide, but I thank you for your concern.

Comment: How did you get those example figures? Is that {example-image-a}? I would have liked to give a MWE but I did not know how to call a figure without having something to call.

Comment: @MacMcMahan if I understood You  correctle, you should just use ```\includegraphics{example-image-a}```

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh Thank you, I will remember that next time.

Comment: @MacMcMahan you are welcome, it would be cool if You mark my answer as useful too =)